# Send form data to database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to collect user input from a form and send it to a database. I don't know how to tell `sqlCmd.Parameters.Add` to use the x, y and result integers at the top of the function.

```
public void UploadDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = ConvertX(sender);
        int y = ConvertY(sender);
        int result = ConvertResult(sender);

        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection();
        sqlCon.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\Dropbox\GridViewSandbox-20160215081718.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GridViewSandbox-20160215081718;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Procudure1", sqlCon); //can't spell typo :|
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@"x", SqlDbType.Int)); //the x int should go in here somehow? 
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@"y", SqlDbType.Int)); //the y int
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@"result", SqlDbType.Int)); //the result int

        sqlCon.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it resolve your issue?

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@"x", SqlDbType.Int) {Value=x});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@x", SqlDbType.Int).Value = x;
```

Comment: I get a invalidCastException here.